Forwarding messages from telegram web app
Good afternoon, now work on algorithm like
user press "invite friends" button in telegram web app, then he see list of his telegram contats and choose reciever of "forwarded" message from himself, but writen by bot or web app.
I wrote telegram bot on aiogramm, web app builded on django framework.
Maybe someone know how to implemnt this, i tried but didnt found anything in network, maybe someone know way to implemt this (method or anything else), thaks to everyone here who can give any help!
